# Insert Data into other model in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have 2 models: (Invoice and Summary)

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    inv_id = models.IntegerField()
    order_id = models.IntegerField()
    unit_price = models.IntegerField()
    num_units = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.inv_id)


class Summary(models.Model):
    invo_id = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sum = models.IntegerField()
```

I need to insert data in Summary table from url and also compute "sum" by using Invoice Table.
I tried:

```
    inv_id = request.GET.get('inv_id').split(',')

    for i in inv_id:
        # summary = Invoice.objects.filter(id=i).annotate(result=F('unit_price') * F('num_units')).aggregate(Sum('result'))['result__sum']
        summary = Invoice.objects.raw('''select id as id,sum(unit_price * num_units) as sum from restapi_invoice where inv_id = {}'''.format(i))
        x = Invoice.objects.get(pk=summary[0])
        # Summary.objects.update_or_create(invo_id_id=x, defaults={"sum": summary[1]})
        p = Summary(sum=summary[1])
        p.save()
        p.invo_id.add(x)
```

it's not working. How can I insert id from url and also compute sum of that id and store in Summary table ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get in by using `F` in django orm.

```
inv_id = request.GET.get('inv_id').split(',')
inv_sums = Invoice.objects.filter(id__in=inv_id).annotate(sum=F('unit_price') * F('num_units'))
for inv in inv_sums:
    Summary.objects.create(invo_id=inv, sum=inv.sum)
```